# How long to install Microsoft Services?

Tags: windows, laptop, installation, microsoft-office, dell-inspiron

I bought a Dell Insperion 15 laptop, with Microsoft Home & Office loaded on it.

During initial boot, there is a screen "Office comes with your device".  In the lower right corner is a button "Got it".  I clicked on it and got a blue screen (not full BSOD).  After 2.5 hours, no visible progress is made.

I can still click on the back button.
[image]

How long should I wait for the next informational screen after clicking on "Got it" button?

Is there something wrong with the laptop (it's about 2 days old)?

Comment: Screenshots might be helpful o clarify your question. If OEM devices come with Office, they typically already have it installed. Are you sure it's not already installed?

Comment: Added the pretty blue screen snapshot.  And this is from the laptop.

Comment: In the upper right corner is "Services".

Comment: Hit Shift+F10, then Alt+Tab back to the main screen?

Comment: @user1686, when I pressed Alt+tab, I get a small black window popping up that is titled "Microsoft Account".  The window disappears when I release the Alt+Tab.  I can go back screens by clicking on the left arrow at the top left of the screen.

Comment: Update:  After 10 hours, no change to the laptop.

Comment: It should not take that long, obviously. Shut the computer down if you cannot interrupt the installation some other way. When it comes back up it may be OK. If it isn't, I'd suggest resetting the computer using the appropriate tools for that computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to contact the retailer.

They gave me a link to a site where I can download a Windows 10 installer onto a USB Drive.  Modified the bootloader to boot off of the USB Drive and rebooted.

Windows 10 is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your internet speeds it should not take very long to install this software. The Office installer isn't as large as it used to be, still several hundred megabytes, but not the several gigs its been before.

If you cannot interrupt the installation some other way I'd hold the power button to shut the computer down. Powering it back on it may work OK. If it continues to have this problem I suggest using following Dell's instructions for resetting the computer. If that fails, you'll want to contact support or the retailer to replace the computer.